# Deploying issues with next web page and vercel

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVjy1.png)

Hi guys,

My webpage is working fine when running on a local server, However when deploying to vercel I appear to be having issues with my code.

Any Help is much appreciated, Ty Ty

I tried to deploy on vercel and hit errors

Comment: Have you run "npm run build" locally, or have you only used "npm run dev"? Maybe running dev isn't doing such strict TS checking.

Comment: I have used npm run build and now see this error. 

 npm run build

> app@0.1.0 build
> next build

image alt errors - (im ignoring for now)

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Linting and checking validity of types ...Failed to compile.

Comment: ./src/components/team/index.tsx:27:30
Type error: Property 'alt' is missing in type '{ className: string; src: StaticImageData; style: { objectFit: "cover"; }; }' but required in type '{ src: string | StaticImport; alt: string; width?: SafeNumber | undefined; height?: SafeNumber | undefined; fill?: boolean | undefined; loader?: ImageLoader | undefined; ... 11 more ...; lazyRoot?: string | undefined; }'.

as well as this error

Comment: Ok, so you just need to fix the TypeScript errors then upload again.

Comment: Ok ty Craig!! Big help, Do you know what I need to do for the type script part? I guess its Eslint that's causing this issue? 

My eslintrc.json contains: 

{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}

Comment: So ESLint is checking your code style and TSC is checking your type safety. It seems like they're both concerned with the same thing, that you aren't setting the "alt" property on your images.

Comment: Also from the screenshot, your code "function(...classes)" does not have type information (hence it's complaining about "implicit any") -- if you're using TypeScript then ideally you need to be adding the type info. If you don't want to use typescript, switch to JavaScript, or use "//ts-ignore" above the lines you want to ignore from checking) NB. ESLint might complain about "ts-ignore" so you then need to ignore that too.